# Connecting to my home router web interface from work

Tags: router, proxy, dynamic-dns, cname, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to connect to my home router web interface from work.

I use dyndns, because I don't have a static IP at home, and it works perfectly from any other place except my workplace (**update:** I made a mistake, see edit below). When trying to access the web interface from work I get a "500 Server Error" with the code: SERVER_RESPONSE_RESET. I'm not trying to use any protocols such as remote desktop, I'm only trying to access the web interface. I can access any other web page from my workplace with no problems, and I think my router web interface is like any other web page, isn't it?

I thought maybe my work place proxy blocks addresses of services like dyndns, so I also applied another trick. Since I have a web page on my own domain (say *www.mydomain.com*) which I can access from work, I tried adding a CNAME to my domain which is linked to the dyndns address (*router.mydomain.com*). This way if anyone enters the address *router.mydomain.com* from anywhere, they reach my home router web interface, and there's no way of knowing it's a dyndns address (or is there?). However, it still doesn't work from my workplace (I get the same error message).

Any ides?

**Edit:** I'm sorry to say I made a mistake earlier. I used to be able to access my home router web interface from my old workplace, and I thought it was still possible since I don't recall making any configuration changes. However, after reading the replies, I went over to my old workplace and checked, and it doesn't work from there either. I'm very sorry for giving out wrong and misleading information about my problem. So to summarize: my problem is that I can't access my home router web interface from *anywhere*.

Comment: As right now it's Sunday in most parts of the world, just to be sure: you're not testing using some Remote Desktop through VPN from home, right? (Maybe it's doable, but it might yield some interesting routes then.)

Comment: No I'm not (for now at least), I'm just trying to access the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts by the tech support of my router's manufacturer (D-Link) to help, they have given up. It seems that I simply have a faulty router, and I need to replace it.
Thanks again to anyone who has tried to help, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

Error 500 normally means error on the side of the server, which in your case is the router itself.

The router administration page is not like any other page, since it is served by the router, not by any other computer in your network.

This might be a problem with your router's settings. If you can't find it, you might considering resetting it to initial state (the security-pin method or other). You might also consider updating the firmware (if update is available).

Yet I am puzzled by your claim that it works from elsewhere. If you mean that you can administer your router from outside your network, just not from your work place, then there might be some filter on the company's firewall that is blocking you. You might try changing the way that you are accessing it, such as page-name (if possible in the router's settings).

Comment: *Error 500 normally means error on the side of the server* Good thinking, that might indeed suggest there is *some* communication. @Joe, any chance you're using Internet Explorer, which is infamous for its "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages" when the server side response [is too small](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807)? Or maybe IE even shows such messages when the server side response is non-existing?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with my router's settings, since I can access it from outside my network, just not from my work place. Changing the way that I access it sounds good, but what is "page-name"? To answer @Arjan, I am using Firefox.

Comment: @Joe: What brand & model is the router?

Comment: D-Link DSL-2760U

Comment: From your [manual](ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ADSL/DSL-2760U_BRU_D/Description/DSL-2760U_user_manual.pdf), this router has many configuration options. What have you configured in the section "Access Control"?

Comment: I have ticked the option HTTP in the WAN column in the "Services" section, and of course changed the Admin password in the "Passwords" section.

Comment: In "Access Control -- IP Address", have you enabled "Access Control Mode" ?

Comment: Considering my slightly different problem (see edit of question), I probably DO have a problem with my router's settings. I would really like to find it without resetting the settings to their initial state, though. To answer your question, I have not enabled "Access Control Mode"

Comment: And what about the router's firewall?

Comment: I haven't found an option to turn off the firewall, but there is a section called "IP filtering". I tried setting up an incoming IP filter for all IP addresses and TCP/UDP protocol on port 80. There is no change in the response I get from web-sniffer.net, but I haven't tried it from my workplace yet.

Comment: You have firewall and QoS in your very complete router. The [manual](ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ADSL/DSL-2760U_BRU_D/Description/DSL-2760U_user_manual.pdf) in pdf format might be easier to search.

Answer (score 1):

> [..] a CNAME to my domain which is linked to the dyndns address (*router.mydomain.com*). [..] if anyone enters the address *router.mydomain.com* [..] there's no way of knowing it's a dyndns address (or is there?)

Surely people (or firewalls) could see it's a `CNAME`, like see `dig www.superuser.com`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.superuser.com.      21600   IN      CNAME   superuser.com.
superuser.com.          9639    IN      A       64.34.119.12
```

But I don't know how smart firewalls are.

A reverse lookup would reveal your internet provider's DNS settings (not the DynDNS records) -- see `dig -x youripaddress` Maybe that address has (meanwhile) been blocked? What if you just type that (dynamic) IP address for testing?

To see what accessing from another computer might yield, the [Web-Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) website might be helpful. Also, while testing, I'd surely recommend to NOT use some Remote Desktop over VPN to get to your work computer from home, and then try to get back to your own router. (Maybe it's doable, but it might yield some interesting routes then, which I guess should be taken out of the use case while troubleshooting.)

Comment: Thank you for comment about CNAME, indeed anyone could see it. I tried my current IP address for testing, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Joe, what if you use that IP address (or CNAME) with http://web-sniffer.net/ ?

Comment: When trying my IP with port 80 or 443, I get "Error 110: Connection timed out". When using any other port (that I've tried), I get "Error 111: Connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

most routers block incoming request from external ip's, maybe there's a setting for allowing remote access?

Comment: I have allowed remote access on my router. As I said, I can connect to it from any other place except from my workplace.

Comment: sorry, I haven't got that. Is your router-webinterface using port 80? Maybe it's another port to don't mess up with running webservers on your LAN, and this port is blocked with your workspace proxy.

Comment: That seems possible, how do I find out which port my router web interface is using?

Comment: @Joe, if you're not specifying a specific port, then your browser uses port 80. When using a specific port, like 8080, then you would be using URLs like `http://router.mydomain.com:8080`

Comment: I was wrong earlier about accessing my router from places except my workplace (see question edit), but I still can't find the problem with my router's settings. I can try and access my router with different ports, but how do I know which ones to try?